# Copying a file and placing it into multiple folders in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I am trying to take a single Google document and send it to multiple folders at the same time. The documents needs to be copied into each one so that if a modification is made in one folder, the document is not modified in the rest of the folders.

I know that you can do it one at a time, but I need to do this for around 150 folders. How can I do this?